# How can I do a rotation to the target point from right?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I have a wheel. I want the wheel to spin towards the target points.

Turns right on 1-2-3-4-5. but it turns left to 6-7-8 points. because it takes a shorter way to turn from the left side. (The points are kept in the "target" variable)

I want the wheel to always turn to the right to point to the target.
How can I do a rotation to the target point from right?

[image]

My code:

```
 targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(
            target.transform.position.x,
            0,
            target.transform.position.z)
            - transform.position);
    transform.rotation =
        Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation,
        targetRotation,
        3f * Time.deltaTime)
        ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution by LiterallyJeff.
[Unity Forum link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/look-rotation-2d-equivalent.611044/)